# I had problem install pip autopy and this were displayed in command prompt could someone help me

Tags: python

Collecting autopy
Using cached autopy-4.0.0.tar.gz (20 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [6 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "C:\Users\fuzai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_2r7sndy\autopy_ac502467bf4f44ceafc652745a402798\setup.py", line 8, in 
from setuptools_rust import Binding, RustExtension
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Comment: As in error trace back says, install setuptools_rust module.

Comment: thank you sir I already solve this problem

Comment: Your welcome. Please make it as solved.